# SQL Server 2008 ROW_NUMBER() order by Clustered PK slow

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a simple query below that joins 3 of my tables. Due to the fact that OFFSET and FETCH statement are no available in SQL Server 2008, therefore I have implemented the ROW_NUMBER() in one of my paginated order report.

```
SELECT * FROM 
( 
    SELECT
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY OrderProductDetail.ID ) AS RowNum, 
      *
    FROM 
      Order JOIN 
      OrderProduct ON Order.ID = OrderProduct.OrderID JOIN
      OrderProductDetail ON OrderProduct.ID = OrderProductDetail.OrderProductID
    WHERE 
      Order.Date BETWEEN '2018-01-01 00:00:00.000' AND '2018-02-01 00:00:00.000'
) AS OrderDetailView
WHERE RowNum BETWEEN 1 AND 1000;
```

With over 16M <strike>3M</strike> records in the Table the above query took 1 minute to complete, records found are capped to 1000.

However, if I simply remove the RowNum in WHERE Clause then the query complete within 3 seconds and total of 1700 records returned. (Also same result if I only run the Sub-Query portion)

```
SELECT * FROM 
( 
    SELECT
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY OrderProductDetail.ID ) AS RowNum, 
      *
    FROM 
      Order JOIN 
      OrderProduct ON Order.ID = OrderProduct.OrderID JOIN
      OrderProductDetail ON OrderProduct.ID = OrderProductDetail.OrderProductID
    WHERE 
      Order.Date BETWEEN '2018-01-01 00:00:00.000' AND '2018-02-01 00:00:00.000'
) AS OrderDetailView
```

- Order.ID = Unique Clustered PK (Int)
- Order.Date = Non-Clustered Index (Timestamp)
- OrderProduct.ID = Unique Clustered PK (Int)
- OrderProductDetail.ID = Unique Clustered PK (Int)

Some other test cases I've performed:

1. ( ORDER BY Order.Date ) AS RowNumber >> Fast
2. ( ORDER BY Order.ID ) AS RowNumber >> Fast

Question: How can I improve the performance?

Comment: Can you share the actual execution plan for both queries and include in the question?  Use this https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/

Comment: Could you try adding `OPTION (RECOMPILE)` at the end of your `SELECT` just as an experiment and let us know the results?

Comment: @Cool_Br33ze Fast Query - https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=Syb58hNjM, Slow Query - https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=rka2U2NsG

Comment: @MK_ I have tried the OPTION but there is no noticeable differences, thanks anyway

Comment: @PeirHwa.Soo - could you indulge me and wrap up the subquery in a CTE instead of it just being a plain subquery?

Comment: @MK_ Yep I tried that too, same outcome :(

Comment: Try `UPDATE STATISTICS ON OrderProduct WITH (FULLSCAN)` (or `sp_updatestats`); the estimates look wonky in general. If that doesn't help, what happens if you add `OPTION (HASH JOIN)`? This is a flaw in the optimizer where the known number of rows (1000) is improperly percolated through the estimates in the joins, causing it to misjudge the efficiency of the join types it's using. One (cleaner) option than `HASH JOIN` if this works is to replace the constant `1000` with a variable (and possibly add `OPTIMIZE FOR (@nums = UNKNOWN)`.

Comment: @JeroenMostert [1] UPDATE STATISTICS doesn't help. [2] OPTION (HASH JOIN) did works! But could you please elaborate more on the "constant 1000 with a variable"? I tried to declare a var @limit=1000 but it doesn't help with the performance.

Comment: My theory was that `WHERE RowNum BETWEEN 1 AND @limit OPTION (OPTIMIZE FOR (@limit UNKNOWN))` would stymie the optimizer's row count estimates and force a different join type. Instead of `UNKNOWN`, a definite but large value like `@limit = 1000000` is also an option. This will force the optimizer to act as if many more rows will be involved, nudging it away from the nested loop joins. To be fair, all of these options are a bit bleh, but explicitly forcing hash joins for everything (even between the tables where it might not be appropriate one day) is definitely the most bleh.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
UPDATE STATISTICS Order WITH FULLSCAN;
UPDATE STATISTICS OrderProduct WITH FULLSCAN;
UPDATE STATISTICS OrderProductDetail WITH FULLSCAN;
```

Finally the query went back to normal after I executed the above commands, my DBA didn't include the FULLSCAN option in first attempt therefore it wasn't working.

Thanks @Jeroen Mostert!